# Extracting specific data from multiple DICOM files

Tags: python, pandas, pydicom

I have multiple DICOM files with similar data, for example:

```
(0008, 0023) Content Date                        DA: '20200209'
(0008, 0033) Content Time                        TM: '192356.853736'
(0010, 0010) Patient's Name                      PN: 'Patient_2'
(0010, 0020) Patient ID                          LO: '123456'
(0018, 1151) X-Ray Tube Current                  IS: '640'
(0020, 0013) Instance Number                     IS: '97',
Dataset.file_meta -------------------------------
(0002, 0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID         UI: CT Image Storage
(0002, 0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID      UI: 1.2.3
(0002, 0012) Implementation Class UID            UI: 1.2.3.4
```

From these files, I wish to extract data tags `'Patient ID'`, `'Patient Name'`, `'Instance Number'` and `'Tube Current'` into a DataFrame, with each Dataframe column corresponding to the data. How could I do this for multiple DICOMS in one list?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using the library `pydicom`, for instance:

```py
for path in dicom_paths:
    tags_list = []
    dicom = pydicom.dcmread(path, force=True)
    if hasattr(dicom, "SliceLocation") and dicom.SliceLocation:
        if "LOCALIZER" not in dicom.ImageType:
            tags = {
                "Patient Name": dicom.PatientName,
                "XRayTubeCurrent": dicom.XRayTubeCurrent,
                "InstanceNumber": dicom.InstanceNumber,
                "Series Description": dicom.SeriesDescription,
                "Image Type": "/".join(dicom.ImageType),
                "Pixel Spacing": list(dicom.PixelSpacing),
                "Rows": dicom.Rows,
                "Columns": dicom.Columns,
                "Image Orientation Patient": list(dicom.ImageOrientationPatient),
                "Series Instance UID": str(dicom.SeriesInstanceUID),
            }
    tags_list.append(tags)
```

where `dicom_paths` is a list that stores the paths of your DICOM files, for instance `Path` objects, where `Path` is imported from the `pathlib` library.

Eventually, you can easily convert your list of dictionaries to a `pandas` dataframe in the following way:

```py
tags_df = pd.DataFrame(tags_list)
```

Pay attention that attributes like `X-Ray Tube Current` are optional (type 3 attribute).

The two `if` statements allow you to skip, for instance, scout images.

Use the autocompletion tool of your IDE to get all the attributes that belong to the `dicom` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using pydicom with dict and list comprehensions, and guarding against missing data:

```
from pydicom import dcmread
from pathlib import Path
from pandas import DataFrame


folder = Path(r"C:\temp\smallCTseries")

datasets = [dcmread(fn) for fn in folder.glob("*")]
keywords = ["PatientID", "PatientName", "InstanceNumber", "TubeCurrent"]

data_dict = {
    keyword: [ds.get(keyword) for ds in datasets]
    for keyword in keywords
}

# Fix PatientName turning into tuple - pandas seems to see it as iterator
data_dict["PatientName"] = [str(x) for x in data_dict["PatientName"]]

# Construct DataFrame, with filename as row index
df = DataFrame(data_dict, index=[Path(ds.filename).name for ds in datasets])

print(df)
```

The `ds.get()` ensures that if the data element is missing, no error is raised, you simply get `None`.

Output using a few files from a PCIR CT set looks like:

```
      PatientID    PatientName InstanceNumber TubeCurrent
CT106  77654033  Doe^Archibald             18        None
CT136  77654033  Doe^Archibald            180        None
CT166  77654033  Doe^Archibald            181        None
CT196  77654033  Doe^Archibald            182        None
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can find all unique dicom studies in a driectory, store the desired information in a dictionary, and also, store series info as a dictionary within dicom study dictionary. [Here is my code](https://github.com/Sdamirsa/PanCanAID/blob/main/Step1_SortingFiles/1_2_Add_Dicom_Meta_to_Table.ipynb).

```
#FINAL 20231216
#My context: I coded this on my windows11 with RTC3080Ti and Corei9-12gen and 32G Ram. I am coding on VS code and using jupyter notebook.
#Your requirment: It doesn't need any exceptional hardward you can run it on an average pc/labtob

import pydicom as pm #for reading dicoms
import os #for looping through system direcotries
from pydicom.multival import MultiValue #for reading dicom metadata
from pydicom.valuerep import PersonName #since tunring dictionary to json raised an error you should use this
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm #for that fancy loop progress, I like it though
import pandas as pd #for tunring dic to excel, first we trasnform it to pandas dataframe
import json #for storing as json

from IPython.display import HTML #so you can click on the sotred excel and json and open it from jupyter notebook

def get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, tag, default=None):
    '''this function will get the dicom tag from the dicom filde for the given tag/code'''
    tag_value = dicom_file.get(tag, None)
    if tag_value is None:
        return default
    if isinstance(tag_value, MultiValue):
        return list(tag_value)  # Convert MultiValue to list
    return tag_value.value

def get_path_to_first_subfolder(full_path, first_subfolder):
    """this will get the path to the first folder of root, which is the subfolder that contains all dicom filed of one dicom study """
    path_parts = full_path.split(os.sep)
    if first_subfolder in path_parts:
        subfolder_index = path_parts.index(first_subfolder)
        return os.sep.join(path_parts[:subfolder_index + 1])
    else:
        return full_path

def count_subfolders(directory):
    '''this will cont the number of files and folders within a direcotyr'''
    total_subfolders = 0
    total_files=0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        total_subfolders += len(dirs)
        total_files += len(files)
    return total_subfolders,total_files 


class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder): #this class will turn our multilevel dictionary into a json file
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, MultiValue):
            return list(obj)  # Convert MultiValue to list
        elif isinstance(obj, PersonName):
            return str(obj)   # Convert PersonName to string
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def ensure_json_extension(directory): 
    '''this function will ensure that definied json direcotry contains the required extension, otherwise, it will add this to the end of definied dir'''
    if not directory.endswith(".json"):
        return directory + "\\JSON.json"
    return directory

def ensure_excel_extension(directory):
    '''this function will ensure that definied excel direcotry contains the required extension, otherwise, it will add this to the end of definied dir'''
    if not directory.endswith(".xlsx"):
        return directory + "\\excel.xlsx"
    return directory

def create_clickable_dir_path(dir_path):
    # Convert the directory path to a file URL
    file_url = f"{dir_path}"
    return HTML(f'<a href="{file_url}" target="_blank">{dir_path}</a>')



def get_dicomdir_give_dicomdicom_datadic(dicom_dir, #direcotry that you want to read, usually dicom studies should be in one folder, preferably with patient unique id/name
                                     dicom_validation=True, #this will check wether the file in the loop is dicom or not. Although make it slower, I recommend using it to ensure only dicom files go through loop 
                                     folder_list_name_indicomdir=None, #In your dicom_dir you can include list of folders name that you want to read. It will not read other folders. Kepp in mind that this will look into subfolders in the main folder, and not the subfolders of subfolders :)
                                     store_as_json_dir=None, #if you want to store your ditionary as json, give your desired json direcotry
                                     store_as_excel_dir=None #if you want to store your ditionary as excel, give your desired excel direcotry
                                     ):
    """
    This function creates a multi-level dictionary for DICOM meta data (named dicom_data) in a directory (named dicom_dir).
    The top level has the last component of dicom_dir, which is the first level subfolder, as a key.
    For each subforled it will store study data within this dic, along with another dicitonary for series data, within this study dictionary.
    For series dictionary the data corresponding for series number will be stored.
    We also have another private_info dictionary within subfodler dictionary.
    
    - dicom_validation: If you set dicom_validation=True, it will validate the file in the loop for being an dicom file. This is super important although it makes code slower.
    Becaouse, sometimes some dicom files have no extension, and also reading other files may cause error in the loop.
    
    - folder_list_name_indicomdir: #In your dicom_dir you can include list of folders name that you want to read. It will not read other folders. Kepp in mind that this will look into subfolders in the main folder, and not the subfolders of subfolders :)
    
    - store_as_json_dir: if you want to store your ditionary as json, give your desired json direcotry
    
    - store_as_excel_dir: if you want to store your ditionary as excel, give your desired excel direcotry
    
    For using this function, the best practice is to place each folder containing one dicom study in subfolder, under the dicom_dir. 
    However, you can change finding unique dicom studies, even placed next to each other beacouse I definied the study_unique=f'{first_subfolder}_{study_id}_{study_date}'.
    If you want your code to be faster you can chane the study_unique to study_unique=first_subfolder. It makes your code 15% faster, sometimes at the cost of incurrect retrival.
    
    """

    total_subfolder,total_files=count_subfolders(dicom_dir)
    print(f'your direcotry contains {total_subfolder} folders and {total_files} files')
    
    last_dir_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(dicom_dir))
    dicom_data = {last_dir_name: {}}

    for root, dirs, files in tqdm(os.walk(dicom_dir), desc="Processing directories", total=total_subfolder,unit='folder'):
        if folder_list_name_indicomdir:
            split_path = root.replace(dicom_dir, '').split(os.sep)
            first_subfolder = split_path[1] if len(split_path) > 1 else ""
            if first_subfolder not in folder_list_name_indicomdir:
                print(f"""The folder {first_subfolder} was not in your definied list.""")
                continue  # Skip if the first subfolder is not in the user-defined list
            
        for file in files:
            if dicom_validation and not pm.misc.is_dicom(os.path.join(root, file)):
                continue # Skip if the it is not dicom file
                   

            try:
                dicom_file = pm.dcmread(os.path.join(root, file))
                study_id = get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0020, 0x0010))
                dicom_data_number = get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0020, 0x0011))
                study_date = get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x0020))
                split_path = root.replace(dicom_dir, '').split(os.sep)
                first_subfolder = split_path[1] if len(split_path) > 1 else ""
                if study_id and dicom_data_number and study_date:
                    study_unique = f'{first_subfolder}_{study_id}_{study_date}' #you can change it for increasing the speed > study_unique=first_subfolder
                    if study_unique not in dicom_data[last_dir_name]:
                        private_info={'name': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0010, 0x0010)),
                                      'institute': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x0080)),
                                      'patient_id': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0010, 0x0020)),
                                      'accession_number':get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x0050))
                                      }
                        
                        dicom_data[last_dir_name][study_unique] = {
                            'dir_to_root': get_path_to_first_subfolder(root, first_subfolder),
                            'study_description': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x1030)),
                            'date': study_date,
                            'age': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0010, 0x1010)),
                            'sex': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0010, 0x0040)),
                            'manufacture_model': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x1090)),
                            'manufacture_brand': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x0070)),
                            'manufacture_brand': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x0070)),
                            'protocol': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0018, 0x1030)),
                            'study_id': study_id,
                            'patient_weight': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0010, 0x1030)),
                            'Image_type': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x0008)),
                            'body_part': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0018, 0x0015)),
                            'modalitty':get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x0050)),
                            'private_info':private_info,
                            'image_dicom_data_list': {}
                        }

                    

                    dicom_data_info = {
                        'dicom_data_description': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0008, 0x103E)),
                        'body_part': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0018, 0x0015)),
                        'slice_thickness': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0018, 0x0050)),
                        'Image_comment': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0020, 0x4000)),
                        'kvp': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0018, 0x0060)),
                        'exposure': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0018, 0x1152)),
                        'exposure_time': get_dicom_tag_value(dicom_file, (0x0018, 0x1150)),
                    }
                    dicom_data[last_dir_name][study_unique]['image_dicom_data_list'][dicom_data_number] = dicom_data_info

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"""Error reading for {file}::: {e} \n """)
                continue
            
    if store_as_json_dir is not None:
        try:
            json_read = json.dumps(dicom_data, indent=4, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)
            store_as_json_dir=str(store_as_json_dir)
            store_as_json_dir=ensure_json_extension(store_as_json_dir)
            with open(store_as_json_dir, 'w') as json_file:
                json_file.write(json_read)
            print(f"""Json stored at :::""")
            display(create_clickable_dir_path(store_as_json_dir))         
        except:
            print(f"""Error storing the json ::: {e} \n """)
            
    if store_as_excel_dir is not None:
        try:
            dataframes = []
            for key, value in dicom_data.items():
                # Convert value to DataFrame if necessary
                df = pd.DataFrame(value)
                # Add the key as a new column or as part of the index
                df['Key'] = key  # Add key as a column
                # df = df.set_index(['Key'], append=True)  # Add key as part of a MultiIndex
                dataframes.append(df)

            # Concatenate all dataframes
            df2 = pd.concat(dataframes).T
            store_as_excel_dir=str(store_as_excel_dir)
            store_as_excel_dir=ensure_excel_extension(store_as_excel_dir)
            df2.to_excel(store_as_excel_dir)
            print(f"""Excel stored at :::""")
            display(create_clickable_dir_path(store_as_excel_dir))          
        except:
            print(f"""Error storing the excel ::: {e} \n """)
            
                                 
    return dicom_data


#example of running code
dicom_dir=r"F:\Data\Big Pancreas (CT, EUS)\Raw Data Hospital\Valid Case" 
save_dir_json=r'F:\Data\Big Pancreas (CT, EUS)\Raw Data Hospital\all_dcm.json'
save_dir_xlsx=r'F:\Data\Big Pancreas (CT, EUS)\Raw Data Hospital\all_dcm.xlsx'


dicom_dic=get_dicomdir_give_dicomdicom_datadic(
    dicom_dir, #direcotry that you want to read, usually dicom studies should be in one folder, preferably with patient unique id/name
                                     dicom_validation=True, #this will check wether the file in the loop is dicom or not. Although make it slower, I recommend using it to ensure only dicom files go through loop 
                                     folder_list_name_indicomdir=None, #In your dicom_dir you can include list of folders name that you want to read. It will not read other folders. Kepp in mind that this will look into subfolders in the main folder, and not the subfolders of subfolders :)
                                     store_as_json_dir=save_dir_json, #if you want to store your ditionary as json, give your desired json direcotry
                                     store_as_excel_dir=save_dir_xlsx #if you want to store your ditionary as excel, give your desired excel direcotry
                                     )
```